# data inconsistency error in multi-threaded env

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

Suppose one class has two variables : a and b.
Now in that class I am updating the values of two variables in a Synchnonized block, and again updating the values of those two variables in different method.

Now two threads are accessing this class. Will it cause the data inconsistency error ???

Ex:

```
    class ABC {
    int a = 9, b = 18;

    public void method1() {
        synchronized (this) {
            a += 10;
            b += 12;
        }
    }

    public void method2() {
        a += 18;
        b += 23;
    }
}
```

Two threads are accessing this object at a time. What will happen ? Whether data consistency will be occur here or not ??

Answer (score 0):

When one thread is running `method2()` nothing stops another to go through `method1()`.  Since `+=` is not an atomic operation you are open to concurrency problems.